Nested Map access key value
In my Firebase Realtime database my schema is.

My model is
class Data {
  final double data;
  final DateTime timestamp;

  Data({
    required this.data,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  factory Data.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Data(
      data: data['data'] ?? 0.00,
      timestamp: (data['timestamp'] != null)
          ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch((data['timestamp']))
          : DateTime.now(),
    );
  }
}

Now I want display just the last key value pair 'data', how do I access that?
StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  _database.child(
                      '/UsersData/C14SAlxF5ma70xxx6wV9d1xxxxx/xxxxx/uplink').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).onValue,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final datat = Data.fromRTDB(
                    Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                      Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.data!.snapshot.value
                          as Map<dynamic, dynamic>),
                    ),
                  );
                  debugPrint(datat.data.toString());
                  return Text(datat.data.toString());
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              }),

I want to display only the latest 'data' in the Text widget.

.limitToLast(1) should work. Doesn't it?

I did try that, if you look at the last code snippet. _database.child(_path).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).onValue,

I noticed. But doesn't that work? What happens? Any error message, or something else we can see here to understand what's not working about the code you shared?

No error  debugPrint(datat.data.toString()); returns '0'

Interesting. I'm not sure how that would happen if the first snippet works. Can you update your question to show a single code snippet that doesn't do what you expect it to do, including that debugPrint and the output you get? It'd also be good if you don't use a _path variable that we can't see the value of, but instead use a hard-coded string value for the path.

Your builder method is not handling errors. Always start them with if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}');

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.
At first glance, your code fails to handle that list.
Something like this:
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  final firstChild = snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.first;
  final values = firstChild.value as as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
  final datat = Data.fromRTDB(
    Map<String, dynamic>.from(values)
  );
  debugPrint(datat.data.toString());
}

I might have some typos in there, but the gist is that you want to get the first child (children[0]) of the result snapshot, and use the value from that.

Yes I agree it a list and I want the result of the firs child.
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<DataSnapshot>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.


Try first instead. Also see https://www.google.com/search?q=The+operator+%27%5B%5D%27+isn%27t+defined+for+the+type+%27Iterable%27.+Try+defining+the+operator+%27%5B%5D%27

Thank you, solution were
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final firstChild =
                            snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.first;
                        final values =
                            firstChild.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                        final datat =
                            Data.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(values));
                        debugPrint(datat.data.toString());
                        return Text(datat.data.toString());
                      } 


Good to hear you got it working, Johan. How is that snippet in your last comment different from the one in my answer (I want to make sure the answer shows the correct code)?

There are a few braces and it should be last not first. The last is just incase you had more than one item in your list.
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final firstChild =
                            snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.last;
                        final values =
                            firstChild.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                        final datat =
                            Data.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(values));
                        debugPrint(datat.data.toString());
                      }

